# Angularjs 2 folder structure and imports

Tags: angular

I want to structure my Angularjs 2 project as this:

```
/app
    /dashboard
        ...
    /hero-detail
        ...
    /heroes
        heroes.component.ts
        heroes.component.html
        heroes.component.css
    /services
        hero.service.ts
    app.component.ts
    app.component.css
    main.ts
/bin
index.html
styles.css
tsconfig.json
```

According to the example application in the docs. I suppose this is one common way of structuring the project. What I wonder is, is there some config setting that I could use to make the import statement relative to the root of the project, instead of to the file it is in.

With a plain structure, the imports looks as (in the file heroes.components.ts):

```
import {HeroService} from './hero.service';
```

But with the structure above, I have to write something like:

```
import {HeroService} from '../services/hero.service';
```

I guess that there is a way one can do this and skip the .. "up-one-dir" notation. Is there?

Right now I get some confusing error in the console which I guess has to do with some import error (because of the relative paths above?):

```
GET http://localhost:3000/heroes/app/main.ts 404 (Not Found)
```

The path is obviously wrong but I cannot find where in my project that should be.

Comment: have a read about this https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039 . it describes some ways of achieve what you need.